# counting nodal domains of equilateral triangle

Tags: java, matrix, clipping

i am developing a code to count nodal domains of any figure based on matrix so recently i was supposed to check my program for equilateral triangle but due to sqrt(3) factor it fails in clipping it properly that is why count is getting wrong any help is appreciable

```
private void sin()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j <col; j++)
            {

                   a=Math.cos(((2*m)-n)*((2*(i+1))/3)*pi);
                   b=Math.sin(((2*(n*(j+1)))/1.732)*pi);
                   c=Math.cos(((((2*n)-m)*(2*(i+1)))/3)*pi);
                   d=Math.sin(((2*m)*(j+1)/1.732)*pi);
                   e=Math.cos((((m+n)*(2*(i+1)))/3)*pi);
                   f=Math.sin((((m-n)*(2*(j+1)))/1.732)*pi);
                   mul=(a*b)-(c*d)+(e*f);

                if(mul<0)
                {
                    matrix[i][j]=0;
                }
                else
                {
                    matrix[i][j]=4;
                }
                //System.out.print(matrix[i][j]);
            }
            //System.out.println();
        }


    }
```

following is code which is used to extract a equilateral triangle from function in help is needed in this only

```
    private void eqltri()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        for (int i = 0; i <row; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j <col; j++)
            {
                if( i>(j/t)&& (row-i)>(j/t))

                {
                    matrix[i][j]=matrix[i][j];
                }
                else
                {
                matrix[i][j]=4; 
                }
                //System.out.print(matrix[i][j]);
            }
            //System.out.println();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void eqltri()
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j <col; j++) 
                {
                    xx=(i+1)*pi;
                    yy=(j+1)*pi;
                    if((xx*t)>yy&& yy<(t*(p-xx)))

                    {
                        matrix[i][j]=matrix[i][j];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    matrix[i][j]=4; 
                    }
                    //System.out.print(matrix[i][j]);
                }
                //System.out.println();
            }

        }
```